# How to build a simple string from a multidimensional array?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, multidimensional-array

Basically, I have a multidimensional array that I need to build into a simple string.

Quite an easy question, although it has been eating away at me for quite some time now since I can't seem to nail it.

Here is an example of how my array could look with just 3 questions within it:

```
[["question1","answer1","answer2","answer3","answer4"],["question2","answer1","answer2","answer3","answer4"],["question3","answer1","answer2","answer3","answer4"]]
```

For example, `D.rows[0][0]` would be "question1" and `D.rows[2][3]` would be "answer3", just to clarify.

Here is how it must be saved into a string as:

```
question1,answer1,answer2,answer3,answer4 
question2,answer1,answer2,answer3,answer4 
question3,answer1,answer2,answer3,answer4
```

Each element must have a comma between them, and each question must be separated by a line-break.

This is what I currently have that is not working:

```
var fullString;
for (i = 0; i < csvArray.length; ++i) 
{
    second = secondArray[i];
    for (j = 0; j < second.length; ++j) 
    {
        fullString += entry[j] + "'";
    }
    fullString += "\n";
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
var s,a=[["question1","answer1","answer2","answer3","answer4"],"question2","answer1","answer2","answer3","answer4"],["question3","answer1","answer2","answer3","answer4"]];
for(i=0; i < a.length; i++){
    s=(s)?s+"\n\r"+a[i].join():a[i].join();
}
```

[jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/jaakkytt/yd7mr/)

In your own example: since you are going straight to adding to `fullString`, it should have an empty string for value, otherwise you will end up with `undefined` in the beginning.

```
var fullString="";
```

this part `second = secondArray[i];` should have been

```
var second = csvArray[i];
```

and in a same way this `fullString += entry[j] + "'";` should have been

```
fullString += second[j] + ",";
```

Comment: @fizzix - in for in loop order of iteration is not specified in ecma script spec - results may vary in different browsers, also if you add to array prototype in ES3, you will get that too - use for(i=0; i < arr.length; i+=1)

Comment: thanks @magyar1984 for the notice, been on ES5 for a while now and tend to forget some of the differences ^^. But personally I would even recommend going with the answer given by spy-js

Answer (score 1):

one liner:

`var result = [["question1","answer1","answer2","answer3","answer4"],["question2","answer1","answer2","answer3","answer4"],["question3","answer1","answer2","answer3","answer4"]].join('\r\n');`

Answer (score 0):

something like this:

var questionAnswerSet= { "question1" : [
                                    { "answer1" : "value", 
                                      "answer2"  : "value",
                                      "answer3"  : value}
                                  ],
                            "question2"   : [
                                    { "answer1" : "value", 
                                      "answer2"  : "value",
                                      "answer3"  : value}
                                  ], 
                }

and access like this:

questionAnswerSet[0].answer2 // question one answer 2

questionAnswerSet[1].answer2 // question two answer 2

Comment: Sorry, but that makes no sense at all? I believe that I need a double for loop to go over every element within my array.

Comment: My array can have any amount of entries? And the elements will always be different...

Answer (score 0):

If you have an array as this...

```
var arr = [["question1","answer1","answer2","answer3","answer4"],["question2","answer1","answer2","answer3","answer4"],["question3","answer1","answer2","answer3","answer4"]];
```

then...

```
var strArr  =  arr.join(',');
var strLine =  arr.join('\n'); // string with line breaks.
```

will do that for you.

if you want different strings for each question-answer block, then...

```
var strJoinArr = [], strJoinLines = '';
for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
    strJoinArr.push(arr[i].join(','));
    strJoinLines += arr[i].join(',')+ '\n'; // string with line break
}
```

then to access each section you can use indexes,

For example, `strJoinArr[2]` will return `'question3,answer1,answer2,answer3,answer4'`

more on [`.join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)
more on [`.push()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push)

Comment: How does that add the line breaks?

Answer (score 0):

```
for (var i=0; i<yourArray.length; i++) { // iterate on the array
   var obj = yourArray[i];
   for (var key in obj) { // iterate on object properties
      var value = obj[key];
      console.log(value);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be your solution if you plan ot change separators or number of answers.

```
var array = [["question1","answer1","answer2","answer3","answer4"],["question2","answer1","answer2","answer3","answer4"],["question3","answer1","answer2","answer3","answer4"]],
string = "";

for (var i = 0; i <= array.length - 1; i++) {
     string +=array[i].join(', ');
     string += "\n";
}
```

Also, in the less readable but also effective way, for any object of this structure

```
string = array.join('\r\n');
```